# Firestore - can you retrieve a document and a sub collection list in a single call?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to retrieve a Firestore doc and all the items in a specified sub collection in a single call?

Answer (score 0):

No.  You have to `get()` the parent document, then separately `get()` the query for the each nested subcollection separately.